# todonotes error on TeX Live 2016

Tags: packages, todonotes, texlive-2016

I just upgraded to Tex Live 2016 on a Mac and doing a pdflatex on any document that includes the todonotes package (whether actually used or not) now throws this error:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/todonotes/todonotes.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
! Undefined control sequence.
l.444 \ifGin@setpagesize
```

Documents do build, and any notes do in fact show up in the pdf, but the error is consistent across docs that load todonotes. Has anyone else seen this behavior?

Comment: load color or graphicx before todonotes (or actually before xcolor) or wait for the next  texlive update when the error will be gone

Comment: Update: I'm seeing the same error building a CV Modern resume, without todonotes loaded.

Comment: it's xcolor that generates the error todonotes is only involved as far as it loads xcolor. if loading graphicx isn't easy just put `\expandafter\newif\csname ifGin@setpagesize\endcsname` as the first line of the document, or, as I say, a texlive update today or tomorrow should fix it, depending on which mirror you use.

Answer (score 3):

This error is already avoided in the texlive sources so will be fixed at the next update, today or tomorrow, until then if you load `graphicx` before `xcolor` or even just

```
\expandafter\newif\csname ifGin@setpagesize\endcsname
```

to define `\ifGin@setpagesize` then the error should go.

Comment: Thanks!  For people who are out of the habit (like me): `tlmgr update --self && tlmgr update --all`